# Appending the header of a txt document with ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion

Using ColdFusion I would like to append the header of the file each time that I add a row into the txt file

The format for the header is as follows:

```
E.g.
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890
BEEP BANK       1000009099810
```

The header's content is broken down into:

```
Element         Description                                        Pad char Pad side    Length
Bank name       First 16 characters of the Bank name as per file   [space]  right       16
                name, padded with spaces at the end if the name is 
                less than 16 characters long. Convert to Uppercase  
Record count    Number of data records in the file, depicted as a  0        left        3
                3 character, zero-left-padded string    
Total value     Value (in cents) of all amounts in the file,       0        left        10
                depicted as a  10 character, zero-left-padded 
                string  
Total Header Record Length  29
```

At the moment I am running a loop and inside of the loop I would like to update the Record Count and the Total Value inside of the header while still keeping the same format

What I would like to know is how do I get the header of the txt file called test.txt and split the numeric value to get the individual values namely Record Count and Total Value to work with them and add my new dynamic values to them?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've read this three times, and I still don't know what you're actually asking. Is it just me?

Comment: Hi Adam, I am quite confused myself but what I am trying to achieve in short: I would like to get the first row of the txt (the header) and update it. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will read the file and replace the first line, and write it back to the original file.

```
    <cffile action="read" variable="textDoc" file="#getDirectoryFromPath(getTemplatePath())#/test.txt" />
    <cfset textDoc = listSetAt(textDoc,1,"new header line","#chr(10)##chr(13)#")>
    <cffile action="write" file="#getDirectoryFromPath(getTemplatePath())#/test.txt" output="#textDoc#">
```

In this instance we are using new-line and carriage-return as the list delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to parse the file. If you want to keep it human readable (as opposed to making it XML or similar) then you have to tell coldfusion how to find the characters to update.

I assume the header is always static, only the numbers recording the records change.

The best way is to include those records in the header by escape characters, for example {{125}}.

Then grab the file, and do a regexp looking for {{.?}}, update the number and replace. Then write the file.

OR just delete the whole header and rewrite with the update data everytime the file is saved. Whichever is easier in your case.